# Solar powered charger for laptop

Tags: solar-panels, power-backup

How do I build a solar powered charger for a laptop with dc rating 19v, 3.42A? I'd also prefer to use some other batteries to store the electricity? How can I accomplish this?

Comment: This may be better suited for the [Electronics Stack Exchange site](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Haven't you asked basically the same question 3 times?

Answer (score 2):

**A.** You will need to calculate your Energy consumption estimations. Let say, for 5 hours a day of average laptop consumption (70W) you will need to produce 450-550w a day (that is 350w plus energy losses on conversion of voltage and losses of battery).

**B.** For this You will need:
1. Some kind of solar panels 
2. A solar charger
3. A battery 
4. An inverter

The specification of those element is depend on the strategy that you're planning to apply.

**C.** There are two basic strategies for planing this system:

1. You can use a 24V system and then get a DC-DC inverter (24v to 19v), OR you can use...
2. Mine preferred way, because the computer is a gentle electronic device, is to go through the transformer of the computer it self (that is, 220/110v AC to 19DC), as you can count on it to be accurate and stable for the computer and the internal battery system: use a 24/12v system with a inverter to normal appliance voltage in your region (220/110v) and plug the original transformer of the computer to the inverter.

You've a lot more to learn before i would recommend you to start spending money on materials.

You can read more [here](http://www.solar-power-answers.co.uk/solardesign.php) (cost 20$) - and I'm not getting paid for this. i don't even know the writer... i really do recommend this e-book, i have used it myself.
and [here you can find](http://www.bayadaim.org.il/2010/12/%D7%9E%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%9B%D7%AA-%D7%A1%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%90%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%AA-1-5-kw/) an full and detailed article i wrote about how to build a solar pv electric system, but it in Hebrew, so maybe try to Google-translate it.

And here two more good pieces of content, from "Instructables":

1. http://www.instructables.com/id/DIY-Solar-Setup/
2. http://www.instructables.com/id/DIY-Home-Solar-Planning-a-Solar-Array-Beginners/

Hope you'll find this answer useful.

Comment: Awesome answer :) +1 for the links too.